# How to use bootstrap 5 with webpack loader?

Tags: reactjs, django, webpack

I am using react with django with webpack, It is the first time to do this, but I faced a problem with webpack loader it says :

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> @charset "UTF-8";/*!
|  * Bootstrap v5.1.3 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
|  * Copyright 2011-2021 The Bootstrap Authors
 @ ./src/components/siteNavbar.js 4:0-50
 @ ./src/App.js 4:0-49 14:40-50
 @ ./src/index.js 1:0-28
```

This is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                // This has effect on the react lib size
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
            },
        }),
    ],
};
```

**I am also using `babel`**
Can you tell me how to configure my webpack file to fit bootstrap, font awesome and many more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was my problem, I am sorry, but I still new with webpack.

I just install these packages:

1. `npm install sass-loader sass webpack --save-dev`
2. `npm install --save-dev postcss-loader postcss`

Then I just edited my `webpack.config.js` file to be like this:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                // This has effect on the react lib size
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
            },
        }),
    ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same error because of the wrong webpack configuration:

```
 {
    test: /\.css$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
  },
```

I've removed `exclude` field from the object.